# O que é e como uso ? Para que uso o ViewDIdLoad?

Tags: ios

O que é e para que serve o ViewDIdLoad ?

Answer (score 4):

É um método da classe *UIViewController* que é chamado assim que a hierarquia de views do view controller é carregada,  mas ainda não está visível na tela.

Esse método é chamado uma única vez durante o ciclo de vida do view controller. 
É normalmente nele que se faz a inicialização de elementos da interface que não foi feita pelo nib/storyboard. Isto é, muita vezes no editor gráfico apenas definimos a estrutura básica da interface, mas a configuração dos elementos (ex: cor,fonte,texto) é feita por código, nesse método. Também podemos outros tipos de inicialização não referentes a interface.